# Installing packages in a virtual environment (not Python) using in-built package manager

Tags: package-management, virtualenv

I want to install packages in Linux via in-built package managers like `portage` for `Gentoo` or `pacman` for Arch. This is not regarding Python packages. I want to set up a virtual environment where all the dependencies and the package itself is installed only in that virtual environment and as soon as the virtual environment is thrown away, everything must go away. I want this because, I don't want any `make` commands or any other way of install like `emerge` or `pacman -S` to affect the directories I work with now i.e. they must be only for a single time use. Many times, it is hard to find where the `make` command extracts and installs the software and necessary files. Since it is only for a single-time use, I don't want those unnecessary dependencies to take up the space in my hard drive. By using a virtual environment, I don't care where the packages, dependencies and other files are installed as they all can be demolished by just deleting the virtual environment.

How to achieve this?

Comment: It's really hard to figure out what you mean, can you clearly explain what it is you want to do?   The best I can tell is that you want to set up temporary, disposable, and isolated run-time environments for individual tasks....which sounds a lot like you should be using linux's container / namespaces features.  Have you considered using container management systems such as [podman](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/) or [docker](https://www.docker.com/) or DIY with [mobyproject](https://mobyproject.org/) or systemd's `nspawn` and `machinectl` tools.

Comment: BTW, installing packages in a linux distro generally does not affect your current working directory, or user files at all.  Packages contain binaries, libraries, config files, data files, documentation, etc to be installed under /usr, /var, /etc and so on.  It would be extremely rare (almost non-existent) for a package to install files under /home.